# Confusion in regex pattern for search

Tags: regex, bash

Learning regex in bash, i am trying to fetch all lines which ends with `.com`

Initially i did :

```
cat patternNpara.txt | egrep "^[[:alnum:]]+(.com)$"
```

*why :* `+`matches one or more occurrences, so placing it after `alnum` should fetch the occurrence of any digit,word or signs but apparently, this logic is failing....

Then i did this : (*purely hit-and-try, not applying any logic really...*) and it worked

```
cat patternNpara.txt | egrep "^[[:alnum:]].+(.com)$"
```

*whats confusing me :* `.` matches only single occurrence, then, how am i getting the output...i mean how is it really matching the pattern???

**Question :**     whats the difference between `[[:alnum:]]+` and `[[:alnum:]].+` (*this one has `.` in it*) in the above matching pattern and how its working???

**PS :**  **i am looking for a possible explanation...not, *try it this way* thing... :)**

Some test lines for the file `patternNpara.txt` which are fetched as output!

```
valid email = abc@abc.com
invalid email = ab@abccom
another invalid = abc@.com
1 : abc,s,11@gmail.com
2: abc.s.11@gmail.com
```

Comment: `.+` matches 1 or more of any character.  So the pattern matches one alnum followed by 1 or more of anything.  If you give it `a.b.com`, it will not match.

Comment: `"^[[:alnum:]]+(.com)$"` works fine.

Comment: @anubhava : its not working on my machine..please see this screenshot of the same => http://i.imgur.com/PkXkA90.png

Comment: @Gene `^[[:alnum:]]+(.com)$` cannot match with `a.b.com` because of the '.' character, but `^[[:alnum:]].+(.com)$` definitely can.

Comment: @NoobEditor What is the content of your patternNpara.txt?

Comment: @leeduhem : it just contains some `paragraphs`, `email id` and some `phone numbers` .....trying to test various patterns through regex in this file!

Comment: @NoobEditor Please include some example lines which you want to match in your question, so we can test our answers.

Comment: @leeduhem : added....3 comments above, there is a screen shot too! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot it seems you're trying to match email address that has `@` character also which is not included in your regex. You can use this regex:

```
egrep "[@[:alnum:]]+(\.com)" patternNpara.txt
```

**DIfference between 2 regex:**

- `[[:alnum:]]` matches only `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. If you have `@` or `,` then you need to include them in character class as well.
- Your 2nd case is including .+ pattern which means 1 or more matches of **ANY CHARACTER**

Comment: WADR,I am not looking for a solution to filter out the lines, i want to understand, why `.+` works whereas only `+` fails to capture the string!!!

Comment: But I thought I have explained why your regex doesn't work. (See note about absence of `@` in your character class).

Comment: Please understand that `[[:alnum:]]` matches only `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. If you have `@` or comma then you need to include them in character class as well.

Comment: still not working => http://i.imgur.com/t71q6yr.png .....also, if `@` is the cause of concern, why is it working in second case but not 1st???

Comment: Your 2nd case is including `.+` pattern which means 1 or more matches of ANY CHARACTER.

Comment: @NoobEditor: Try this regex: `egrep "[@[:alnum:]]+(\.com)" patternNpara.txt`

Comment: dumb dumb dumb....it probably the most dumb question you would have seen...got my mistake now...2nd pattern works `egrep ".+(.com)$"` too...i see my mistake now!!!

Comment: Yes I guessed anchors `^` OR `$` would have been problem too in `"[@[:alnum:]]+(\.com)"`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48152/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-anubhava)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match any lines that end with '.com', you should use

```
egrep ".*\.com$" file.txt
```

To match all the following lines

```
valid email = abc@abc.com
invalid email = ab@abccom
another invalid = abc@.com
1 : abc,s,11@gmail.com
2: abc.s.11@gmail.com
```

`^[[:alnum:]].+(.com)$` will work, but `^[[:alnum:]]+(.com)$` will not. Here is the reasons:

1. `^[[:alnum:]].+(.com)$` means to match strings that start with a `a-zA-Z` or `0-9`, flows two or more any characters, and end with a 'com' (not '.com').
2. `^[[:alnum:]]+(.com)$` means to match strings that start with one or more `a-zA-Z` or `0-9`, flows one character that could be anything, and end with a 'com' (not '.com').

Comment: mate...u r giving me a `solution`, i asked for explanations in the question...(*see the PS part*)???

Comment: @NoobEditor The explanation has been added, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** (with "positive-lookahead") :

```
.+(?=\.com)
```

**Demo :**

http://regexr.com?38bo0